# Can't edit data in TADOTable

Tags: c++, c++builder, adoconnection

I made ​​the connection between C++Builder with access
like this: `ADOConnection> ADOTable> DataSource> DBGrid`

I want to change the value of the current difficulties in this way ADOTable

[image]

```
void __fastcall TForm1::DBGrid1CellClick(TColumn *Column) {
int a, b;
a = ADOTable1->FieldByName("Value1")->AsInteger;
b = ADOTable1->FieldByName("Value2")->AsInteger;
ADOTable1->FieldByName("Total")->AsInteger = a + b;
}
```

When I run the above command directly in case of error.

I hope you understand what I say. because I do not speak English

Comment: You need to specify what error are you getting, at least. Otherwise is impossible to have an idea of what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting field value you need to go into Insert, Append or Edit state:

```
ADOTable1->Edit(); // edit the current record
ADOTable1->FieldByName("Total")->AsInteger = a + b;
ADOTable1->Post(); // save changes
```